# Are morphisms of schemes determined by morphisms of $A$-valued points where $A$ is an affine scheme?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes

Let $X$ be an $S$-scheme. Then by Yoneda lemma we know it's determined by $X(Y) = Hom_S(Y,X)$ where $Y$ ranges over all schemes over $S$.

But it seems like it is enough to consider $Y$ where $Y$ ranges only over all affine schemes over $S$.

Why is this so?

Also, does this extend to morphisms? Suppose we have two $S$-schemes $X_1$ and $X_2$. To give a morphism $f: X_1 \rightarrow X_2$, is enough to give a compatible set of morphisms $f_R : X_1(R)  \rightarrow X_2(R)$ where $R$ is an affine scheme over $S$?

Comment: [Some comment about schemes being obtained by glueing affine schemes over compatible morphisms which I cannot make into a proof of anything.]

Comment: A scheme may be identified with the sheaf it represents on the gros Zariski site of schemes by the Yoneda Lemma. Any scheme admits an affine open cover, so the comparison lemma allows sheaves on the site of all schemes to be identified with sheaves on the site of affine schemes.  I hope that helps your first question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Pedro Tamaroff's comment, the correct idea should be that a scheme is a colimit (gluing) of affine schemes, and as $\rm Hom$ functors preserve colimits, this means that once you know $\rm {Hom}(Y,X)$ for all affine schemes, you can compute what $\rm{Hom}(Y,X)$ has to be for general schemes by writing $Y$ as a colimit of affines.

The details of the statement "every scheme is a colimit of affine schemes" are basic category theory, but you have to find the correct lens to look through. [This MO post gives complete details](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/250068/is-it-always-possible-to-write-a-scheme-as-a-colimit-of-affine-schemes/250076#250076).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. By exactly the reasoning, doesn't it follow that the morphism between two schemes is determined by a set compatible morphisms of $R$-valued points where $R$ is an affine scheme?

Comment: It is not sufficient to ask for just one affine $R$: in general, one must ask for all affine $R$, unless one knows that the morphisms for all affine $R$ factor through some subset of potential $R$. If you know it for all affine $R$, then the answer is probably yes, but I don't really have time to make a precise argument and I'll come back later.

Comment: Yes, I meant for all affine schemes $R$.